# Use an array as the index of another array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to generate random numbers and store them in the array called solution. Then I need to use the generated value of that random array as the index for another array but had no luck. Anyone can help?

```
t = 3
s = 2

L = numpy.zeros((t,s),dtype=int)

solution = np.array([[np.random.randint(1,s+1) for i in range(t)],[np.random.randint(1,b+1) for i in range(t)]]) 

for j in range(t):
    print(solution[0,j])
    L(j,solution[0,j])=1
```

The error it gives me is:

```
L(j,solution[0,j])=1
```

SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Comment: `L` isn't a function so you shouldn't be sending anything to it.

Comment: Try square brackets (for indexing) - `L[j,solution[0,j]]=1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
L[j, solution[0,j]] =1
```

`L` is not a function, but an array. Arrays are indexed with square brackets `[]` not parentheses

Comment: *`passed in`* doesn't sound right - maybe, `Indexing uses square brackets` or something like that.

Comment: Thank you all. That was a stupid mistake I made. Thank you for your help.